# There is a problem with the Find prime number program

Tags: python

The program will run, but it will not print any value.

There seems to be no problem with the code, but I don't know why it doesn't work normally.

This program finds the nth prime number.

```
num=input('enter which order of prime number you want to get: ')  

def find_prime(k):
    '''function that returns k th prime number'''
    cnt=1
    n=2
    passed=[2]
    
    while True:

        if cnt==k:
            return passed.pop(-1)       # get the 'k'th prime number

        for i in passed:
            if n%i==0:      # if n can divided by source in 'passed' n=n+1
                n+=1
                break
        else:               # if n can not divided by source in 'passed' append n to the 'passed' 
            cnt+=1
            passed.append(n)
            n+=1


prime=find_prime(num)
print(prime)
```

There seems to be no problem with the code, but I don't know why it doesn't work normally.

Comment: You say "there seems to be no problem with the code", but of course there IS a problem.  `num` is a string.  You fetch it from `input` and never convert it, so `if cnt==k:` will NEVER be true.

Comment: Notwithstanding the error pointed out by @TimRoberts your algorithm is woefully inefficient. There's also no need to pop the last item from your list. It would also be a good idea to check the value of k to ensure that k > 0 otherwise you'll have an infinite loop